# I need to wrap long text within a container

Tags: html, css, containers, word-wrap

I'm having problems wrapping text within my container. I've already searched and all answers were to put in `word-wrap: break-word;` but it doesn't work for me. I'm must be doing *something* wrong but I'm having trouble finding what.

Here is the website so you may search through the source code: http://www.simplistico.net/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Also, the container background is in red so you may see it clearly.

Comment: It's outside your container. Why would it fit when it's not inside of it? You should specify a width or move it within the container.

Comment: @j08691 That's not the case (at least anymore, maybe the code has been corrected meanwhile). There's a typo in the css file. With a couple of modifications everything works just fine. See my answer below.

Comment: I had a similar problem- my text didn't have spaces in it, so it wasn't broken up into two lines. I know that's not your problem, but posting it here as it took me a while to realize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set a width on your p tag?

```
p {
width:65%;
}
```

**Edit:**

Maybe I should have been more clear. If you have the p tag inside of container already, you don't necessarily need to do it as above. You could do something like.

```
#container p {
width:65%;
}
```

This way only the p tags inside that specified container are affected.

By default a p tag will stretch 100% of its container.Also keep in mind that word-break and Word Wrap are CSS3 properties and only work on certain browsers by default. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Also word break will only break at the boundaries of a container. And because you have a p tag with a default width of 100% inside of another container exceeding your "red background" container. It will break at the boundaries of that container. So technically it is working.

Comment: @Amazonico This would be bad practice unless you really want every paragraph of every page to be 65% width of their container. `.someSpecialPlace p {}` would be more advisable if there's a need to style some tag altogether (unless the whole site is just a couple of pages).

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Kris Hollenbeck and developdaly's answers combined helped fix the problem and it's positioned just how I want it. Thanks again guys!

Comment: No ZZ-bb, its good for me. Its just a couple of pages with some general information on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to position `content`, then you have to explicitly give it a width.

Try:

```
content { width: 600px; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Kris Hollenbeck and developdaly's answers combined helped fix the problem and it's positioned just how I want it. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

First your css file should be `.content {}` (now there's a typo – `content {}` – so anything inside it has no effect what so ever).

Don't know about HTML5 tag `<nav>` so I made the `<ul>` tag to have a class: `<ul class="nav">`. Then added a new style to css file: `nav {float:left}` and removed the `p{word-wrap: break-word;}` style. This works almost perfectly. The red background ends where the content ends so it needs to be taken care of.

UPDATE: To allow the red background color to go all the way down add a css style `.clearfloat{clear:both;}` and put into html file `<br class="clearfloat" />` after the last paragraph inside the `<content>`.

UPDATE2: Ditch the css file's `position` and `left` attributes of the `.content` and adjust the margins of `<nav>` and `<content>` so they are aligned.